# WTForms custom field for dollar values

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm new to WTForms. I wanted to create a new type of field called DollarField which would allow "$" and commas. I would then strip these out and save the value.

I did this which strips off the "$" and removes commas but now all the normal validation that works for DecimalField (e.g. catching cases if the user types in "asda") don't work.

```
class DollarField(DecimalField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if len(valuelist) == 1:
            self.data = [valuelist[0].strip('$').replace(',', '')]
        else:
            self.data = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that because you override `process_formdata`, you are replacing the default processing code (which attempts to convert the string into a decimal, and thus raises an error if it cannot) with your own code. You'll want to make sure that your implementation of `process_formdata` manually calls the parent's `process_formdata` method so that its logic is also run, like so...

```
class DollarField(DecimalField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if len(valuelist) == 1:
            self.data = [valuelist[0].strip('$').replace(',', '')]
        else:
            self.data = []

        # Calls "process_formdata" on the parent types of "DollarField",
        # which includes "DecimalField"
        super(DollarField).process_formdata(self.data)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. This was helpful. but something is still not quite working. if i print out self.data before the call to the parent's process_formdata. i'll have a number like "4567", but after the call, all that is left is "4". it only keeps the first digit.

Comment: @user3152410: If someone is trying to help you with something, please don't simply say that something is "not working". There is no way we can help you unless we know specifically what you mean by "not working". Is it exhibiting the same behavior you are experiencing in the main question? Is it raising an error?

Comment: yeah. i hear you. i tried to explain what was not working by the following: " if i print out self.data before the call to the parent's process_formdata. i'll have a number like "4567", but after the call, all that is left is "4". it only keeps the first digit. "....i'm not sure how else to describe the new problem

Comment: Remember that `process_formdata` does NOT expect a string to be passed to it; it expects a LIST of strings. Make sure that your logic causes whatever is passed to `process_formdata` to STILL be a list, even if that list has only one element. If you pass it a string, it will try to take the first item from the string (the first character) and convert that to decimal. If you are still having a problem with this, ask a new question.

Comment: @user3152410: No problem. Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful so others know that your question has been answered.

Comment: The 'if else' logic in there will give you problems. Apply the transformation to all members of the list.